# Sort a NSMutuableArray

Tags: xcode, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray that is loaded with a inforamtion from a dictionary...

```
[self.data removeAllObjects];  
NSMutableDictionary *rows = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[acacheDB.myDataset getRowsForTable:@"sites"]];      
self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[rows allValues]];
```

There are two key value pairs in the rows dictionary.

I need to sort the self.data NSMutableArray in alphabetical order.

How is this accomplished??

thanks
tony

Answer (score 4):

If the values are plain strings you can use the following to create a sorted array:

```
NSArray *sorted = [values sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: Bad. Always use localized comparison. Also judging from OP's snippet he has more problems than just sorting an array, which he apparently is just not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
[self.data removeAllObjects];
NSArray *values = [[acacheDB.myDataset getRowsForTable:@"sites"] allValues];
NSSortDescriptor *alphaDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"DCFProgramName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortedValues = [values sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:alphaDescriptor, nil]];
[alphaDesc release];
[self.data addObjectsFromArray:sortedValues];
```

1. There's no need to clear an `NSMutableArray` if you're replacing it shortly afterwards.
2. There's no need to create an additional `NSMutableDictionary`, if you're not modifying anything in it.
3. There's no need to create an additional `NSMutableArray`, if you could just as well just add the values to the existing one.

Also: There are some serious **memory leaks** in your code. *(2x alloc + 0x release = 2x leak)*

**Edit**: updated code snippet to reflect OP's update on data structure.

Comment: Your code fails at the sortedValues line....     011-06-09 10:34:18.726 ELC[8660:207] Document Ended Parsing...
2011-06-09 10:34:18.750 ELC[8660:207] -[__NSCFDictionary localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6be5ba0
2011-06-09 10:34:18.757 ELC[8660:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6be5ba0'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: memory management comes later, once the code works, then i clean it up.

Comment: Well, judging by your snippet your data contains NSStrings that you want to be sorted. Your crash log however hints at your data containing NSDictionaries instead. Please give more insight on the structure of `self.data`'s content. Otherwise one can only guess what you might need. Also: If possible always go right away with correct code (especially if all it needs is adding an `autorelease`). As your code grows it gets more difficult to remember all required fixes and makes debugging way more difficult than necessary. Anyway, pleas eprovide more info on `self.data`'s internals.

Comment: Yes, as indicated in the code snippet, rows is a dictionary of two keys and values.     self.data is printed as  Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
Printing description of data:
(
        {
        DCFProgramName = "RAINDROP CHILD CARE CENTER";
        programid = 2024;
    },     there are currently 455 objects is the dictionary  I need to sort the dictionary on the DFProgramName field alpha.

Comment: So to summarize: You have an array of dictionaries. And you now want the array to be sorted by the dictionaries' "DCFProgramName"-key. Is that correct?

Comment: summary correct....   code fails         2011-06-09 11:53:32.881 ELC[9412:207] -[__NSArrayI sortUsingDescriptors:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x70b6400
2011-06-09 11:53:32.885 ELC[9412:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI sortUsingDescriptors:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x70b6400'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(

Comment: My bad, should have been `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors `, not `sortUsingDescriptors `. Fixed code in answer as well.